# How to install and run odoo project from github on ubuntu?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, github, odoo

I have installed odoo11 on ubuntu (via parallels on mac) and the odoo server is up and running fine.Now my client asked me to install his odoo project on my pc. He gave me the github repo link and i dont know how to go about from here. Should i just copy the custom modules or clone the entire project? If i clone the entire project, how do i run the odoo service from there?
I am new to odoo so i need some guidance on this. 
Thanks

[Click here to see the odoo server image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk5WX.png)

[Click here to see the github project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMJAd.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you are running an Odoo instance, your have to mention a config file in the executable command with `-c` or `--config` option. In this config file there is a derivative `addons_path`.

All you have to do is to clone the repository, and add the directory of addons (from the look of your screenshots, `custom, enterprise, inception_modules, nerku, softtech`) in the `addons_path` of your config file. after that, you will find your client addons in Odoo application `apps` page. For more information, you can follow the [official documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/cmdline.html).